# How to store multiple value types in a property?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have an events class that I'm creating, that currently looks like the following:

```
public class SharePointOnErrorEventsArgs : EventArgs
{
    public SharePointOnErrorEventsArgs(string message, bool showException, Exception exception)
    {
        Message = message;
        Exception = exception;
        ShowException = showException;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property to allow the storage of a more verbose and explainable error message
    /// </summary>
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Object to store full exception information within
    /// </summary>
    public Exception Exception { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Boolean value allows for verbose messages to be sent up the stack without
    /// the need for displaying a full exception object, or stack trace.
    /// </summary>
    public bool ShowException { get; private set; }
}
```

Now, instead of sending `true` or `false` for `showException` I'd like  to send one of three values `Debug`, `Info` or `Error` - how can I tackle something like this? I don't  really want to use a string as I want to always restrict this to one of those three values, but I'm unsure how to approach this when using properties.

Comment: It's an `enum` you're looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an enum:

```
public enum ShowExceptionLevel
{
    Debug,
    Info,
    Error
}
```

So your class will be:

```
public class SharePointOnErrorEventsArgs : EventArgs
{

    public enum ShowExceptionLevel
    {
        Debug,
        Info,
        Error
     }

    public SharePointOnErrorEventsArgs(string message, ShowExceptionLevel showExceptionLevel, Exception exception)
    {
        Message = message;
        Exception = exception;
        ShowException = showException;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property to allow the storage of a more verbose and explainable error message
    /// </summary>
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Object to store full exception information within
    /// </summary>
    public Exception Exception { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Boolean value allows for verbose messages to be sent up the stack without
    /// the need for displaying a full exception object, or stack trace.
    /// </summary>
    public ShowExceptionLevel ShowException { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you - I'll read up on those now. Will accept an answer as soon as I can.